# FaultException in WPF application still throws the error in WCF service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, faultexception

I'm trying to create a *FaultException* in my WCF service, so that I can display the error in my WPF application. The problem that I am having is that the FaultException still displays/crashes to my service and does not want to display the error in my WPF application(in the messagebox).

Here is my coding:

**Service**:

```
public void AddNewSupplier(SupplierData Data)
{
    using (Database db = new Database())
    {
        var supplier = new Supplier
        {
            Name = Data.Name,
            Address = Data.Address,
            ContactNumber = Data.ContactNumber,
            Description = Data.Description,
            Terms = Data.Terms
        };
        if (db.Supplier.Any(sup => supplier.Name.Contains(sup.Name)))
        {
            throw new FaultException(new FaultReason("The database already contains the name " + supplier.Name + ". Please enter a diffirent name"), new FaultCode("Multiple Items"));
        }
        else
        {
            db.Supplier.Add(supplier);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client Side Application**:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (MKCServiceClient service = new MKCServiceClient())
    {
        try
        {
            service.AddNewSupplier(new SupplierData
            {
                Name = txtName.Text,
                Address = txtAddress.Text,
                ContactNumber = txtContactNumber.Text,
                Description = txtDescription.Text,
                Terms = txtTerms.Text
            });                
        }
        catch (FaultException fe)
        {
            if (fe.Code.Name == "Multiple Items")
                MessageBox.Show(fe.Reason.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: WCF exceptions will only come across the wire if the exception goes 'unhandled' in the server side logic. So if you have a parent level try/catch it too will need to rethrow to the client

Comment: Thanks for the comment! @pnm - Parent level try/catch? There is no other try and catch in my `AddNewSupplier` method and the only try/catch in my application works fine, but the *service* exception still gets thrown first, where it should not even have been thrown at all.

Comment: Is your service exception making it to the client? Is so, it might be wrapping your fault exception. check the service exception's InnerException property.

Comment: It reaches the client, but only if I insert a breakpoint in the client's method. Otherwise, the InnerException in my service is `null`.

Comment: add the following below your existing catch() in your client method:  catch(exception ex) {throw;} place a break point on that and see if the exception coming back has your exception as an inner exception.

Comment: I've done like you said and placed the breakpoint at `catch (Exception) { throw; }`, but for some reason I can't step over the `else` in my service and then it doesn't want to hit the new catch breakpoint in my client application

Comment: EDIT: Oky, for some reason the `MessageBox.Show` actually works perfectly in the client side and it gives me the correct message, but now all I need to do is to stop the exception being thrown in my service. It's really annoying, because I can't continue to use my client application after the service exception has been thrown...

Comment: note that 'throw' is in essence a return statement. the debugger will effectively 'step out'.

Comment: Does the 'throw' need to be in the service coding or application? Just making sure

Comment: Correct, the throws would typically only need to be inside the service.  Without seeing more of your server/client infrastructure it will be difficult to provide further guidance.  If you're only seeing a 'unhandled exception' dialog in the debugger, this won't be seen by a user once deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you place the breakpoint in your Catch(...) area? What is the real value of `fe.Code.Name` property?

Comment: Let me check quickly ;)

Comment: Ok, so when I place a breakpoint at `fe.Code.Name`, it throws the error in my service and then it opens up the `MessageBox.Show` in my Application, but when I remove the breakpoint, it throws the exception in my service and gets stuck at the `else` for some reason and doesn't run through all the code...

Comment: try to change FaultException type in Catch(...) to the just Exception type. Maybe there is another exception?

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that, as i'm getting all my data from my *service model* I need to use `FaultException` or else I would not be able to catch the exception at all